# Snowflake - unnest column getting error: invalid argument > types for function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a MONTHLY_BUDGETS column that looks like this in the "BTR"."IO_LINMS":

```
[{"id": 11, "quantity_booked": "12", "budget_booked": "0.0", 
"budget_booked_loc": "0.0", "quantity_delivered": "22", 
"budget_delivered": "0.0", "actual_cost_loc": "0.0"}]
```

I've tried the below:

```
SELECT
MONTHLY_BUDGETS[0]:id::integer as monthly_budgets_id
from "BTR"."IO_LINMS"
```

but I get this error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 2 at position 15 Invalid argument
> types for function 'GET': (VARCHAR(16777216), NUMBER(1,0))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to incroprate `parse_json` and `lateral flatten` in to your SQL.

Lateral flatten is needed because your data structure is an array.

The following code will give you id from example data

```
with d as (select parse_json('[{"id": 1590482}]') m)
select v.value:id::integer as monthly_budgets_id
from d, lateral flatten(input => m) v
```